# Porque ajax post request para o controller não funciona?

Tags: codeigniter

Estou a usar codeigniter, precisei de executar uma função(parm1) do model na view, para tal, como recomendado fiz um request para o controller, no controller leio o model e chamo a função.

Estou a fazer debug(error_log), dentro do metodo ao qual chamo no request.

**[controller]**

```
class BaseController extends CI_Controller {

    public function getAgendaDate()
    {
        error_log('herre');
        $this->load->model('agenda_model');
        $this->agenda_model->getAgendaDate();
    }
}
```

No entanto, obtenho status 200 ok no request, mas nada é imprimido para o meu ficheiro de logs, daí concluir que não está a entrar na função.  Como resposta, do request recebo a minha home.php quando deveria receber o resultado de uma query. Relembro que o post obteve status 200, mas não entrou no método ao qual chamei.

**[view]**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "basecontroller/getagendadate",
    type: "POST", //send it through get method
    data: { 
        date: '02-02-2019'
    },
    success: function(response) {
                   console.log(response);
            },
    error: function(xhr) {
            //Do Something to handle error
            console.log(xhr)
        }
    });
```

**Codeigniter 3.1**

Alguém tem ideia do que possa estar a acontecer?

Comment: Talvez sua configuração necessite chamar o _index.php_ antes de declarar o _controller/method_ (Algo como: example.com/index.php/basecontroller/getagendadate). E vc não pode concluir que o _method_ `getAgendaDate()` não está sendo chamado. E se ele estiver sendo chamado e não retornando nada? Lembre-se de indicar a versão do CI que vc está usando.

Comment: Estou trabalhando em localhost, http://localhost/nomeprojeto/index.php/controller/method não funciona, sou redirecionado novamente para a home page.
@ShutUpMagda sim eu posso saber, porque meus error_logs não são imprimidos.

Comment: **Não, não pode**. O que vc quer fazer com `$this->agenda_model->getAgendaDate();`? Onde está a saída desse `method`? Pq vc não mostra o que esse `method` está fazendo? Se ele estiver retornando um `array` ou um `object`, **seu debug não vai servir pra nada** pq **não tem saída**. O programa não vai fazer o que vc quer que ele faça, vai fazer o que vc mandar fazer.

Answer (score 3):

Olá, bom dia! Você precisa chamar o caminho completo da URL no parâmetro `url`, dentro da sua view, assim:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?=site_url('basecontroller/getAgendaDate')?>", // <--- OBSERVE AQUI
    type: "POST",
    data: { 
        date: '02-02-2019'
    },
    success: function(response) {
                   console.log(response);
            },
    error: function(xhr) {
            //Do Something to handle error
            console.log(xhr)
        }
    });
```

Comment: Não funciona, fui redirecionado para a minha home page. No header o request está indo assim http://localhost/calendar/?basecontroller/getAgendaDate

Comment: De fato está errado porque há um ponto de interrogação na URL, fazendo com que tudo após ele seja o nome de uma variável GET. Confira no arquivo `config.php` em `/application/config` se a variável da base URL não está erroneamente com este `?`: `$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/calendar/?'`;

Answer (score 0):

É mais facil utilizar dessa maneira

```
$.post('<?=base_url("basecontroller/getagendadate")?>', {
                parametro1: parametro1,
                parametro2: parametro2
},function(data){
    if(data){
        console.log('ok');
    }
});
```